# How to enable autoscaling/v2beta2 in google cloud

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

While following the tutorial found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/), I saw that I need autoscaling/v2beta2 for having custom metrics for the Horizontal Pod Autoscaler, but don't know how to enable it.

**Environment details:**

- Google Cloud platform
- Kubernetes version 1.13.7-gke.8 (latest)

**What did I try:**

- Using "kubectl api-versions", I checked what API groups I have enable for autoscaling and have only the following:
  autoscaling/v1
  autoscaling/v2beta1
- I found the following [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/) that says "Certain resources and API groups are enabled by default. They can be enabled or disabled by setting --runtime-config on apiserver. --runtime-config accepts comma separated values.". Taking a look at the [kube-apiserver command documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/) , I could find a way to use this command for gcloud

Comment: This has already been cross-posted to [sf], where it is on topic.

Answer (score 6):

**Update**: upgrade your cluster to at least 1.15.5 to get `autoscaling/v2beta2`.

---

Currently, GCP is not supporting `autoscaling/v2beta2`. This issue has been already reported to google, more details and progress changes can be observed at: https://issuetracker.google.com/135624588

However, you can use it freely in Minikube and Kubeadm.